# Trouble opening files in python with VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I can't seem to open basic text files when I run a python script in VS Code, the code runs fine when I use it in Idle but VSCode will give me a FileNotFound error, is there some sort of extension that allows me to do this? Right now I'm only using the Python and Code Runner extension. example of my code:

```
def getInput(textFile):
    file=open(textFile,'r')
    print(file.readlines())
```

Comment: Are you using the absolute path to the file ?

Comment: To add on to what @JacobIRR is asking, perhaps the execution directory is not what you think it is (and is different between IDEs, which would explain Idle vs Code discrepancies). If that's the case, adding the exact `FileNotFound` error and your directory structure will help us diagnose the issue.

Comment: @JacobIRR: file is not keyword for python 3. Just saying.

Comment: @Rahul did not realize that, thanks

Comment: In VS code relative path works. The code runner runs the file from the directory you are in.

Comment: i wasn't using the absolute path but it seems that it can't find the absolute path eitherFileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\Users\\<name>\\Desktop\\Assignment 2\\DNA_String.txt'

Comment: @ValKobilaski Please provide entire traceback.

Comment: You want to open the file for reading in the python code. I want to open the file in the vscode editor with a python command.How is that?

Comment: Could you solve this issue? I am also facing this issue but I am not able to get any solution.

For me, I have opened a folder say `.\documents\python\practice\ `. This folder has various folders for different scipts, like hello world folder with a helloworld.py file, etc. But when I try to open a file from inside the python file, it searches for the file in practice instead of in project folder. What to do here?

Answer (score 15):

Try setting

> "python.terminal.executeInFileDir": true,

in your VSCode Settings

Comment: I changed this in the setting. Also added `"cwd": "${fileDirname}"` in the settings.json as per some other answer here. But still when I open any python file in vs, it starts with the open directory folder path instead of actual file path.

So let's say I have opened `.\documents\python\practice\ ` folder and the file that I am working is in `.\documents\python\practice\project 1\ ` folder along with other files I am opening, still vs code looks for those files in the practice folder instead of project 1 folder. How to solve this?

Answer (score 6):

In your VSCode for Windows

File --> Preferences --> Settings --> (User)Extensions --> Python -->

**Terminal: Execute In File Dir** --> Check It

or

File --> Preferences --> Settings --> Search Settings --> **python.terminal.executeInFileDir**

Comment: Thank you!  Quick easy answer to something I had been pulling my hair out on for the past hour.  Much Appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you need to debug, you need to change the path of the file to open it in debug mode by simply:

1. Going to the explorer
2. Right click on the file and click on copy relative path
3. Put that path in open

That should help you!