# Python code won't open file in virtual studio code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, file-not-found

So I have an assignment for college in python and for a part of it, I need to open the file "voting.txt". I coded up the assignment in Pycharm, as that's the IDE we use in college, but my preferred IDE is VSCode. In Pycharm the code works fine. I run the code and I get the results I want. However, when I try to run the code in VSCode, I get a FileNotFoundError. The file I want to open is in the same directory as the code that opens it. I don't know whether there's a setting that tells VSCode to look for the file in a specific directory, or what, but I'm hoping someone will have a solution. Below is the python code to open the file, so as you can see, the syntax is correct, and as i said, the text file and the python file containing the code that opens it is in the same directory:

```
fileOut = open("voting.txt", "r")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49143852/trouble-opening-files-in-python-with-vs-code

Comment: Try using absolute path instead.  The working directory (`os.getcwd()`) is probably different between your VSCode and PyCharm.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trouble opening files in python with VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49143852/trouble-opening-files-in-python-with-vs-code)

Comment: Is it possible to open a file in the VSEditor from a python script. Such as `code 'file.py'`