# VS Code and python debugger returning error but can run in the terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I am trying to run the code I have made for some plots and I can fully run it on terminal and spyder (I want to switch from spyder to VS code complete for data analysis) but I keep receiving an error saying my CSV file is not found, while if I run this directly on my terminal or spyder I don't get such error

So if I try to run my code using the run cell from VS Code I get this error:

```
import pandas as pd...
import pandas as pd...
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
      4 
      5 
----> 6 LNA_w2Path_PAC_AND_PSP = pd.read_csv('../../Results/CSV/LNA_w2Path_PAC_AND_PSP.csv')
      7 LNA_w2Path_PAC_AND_PSP.columns = LNA_w2Path_PAC_AND_PSP.columns.str.strip().str.lower().str.replace(' ', '_').str.replace('(', '').str.replace(')', '').str.replace('/', '').str.replace('=','_').str.replace(';','')
      8 plt.figure()

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, tupleize_cols, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision)
    700                     skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines)
    701 
--> 702         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
```

Sorry for the not wrapped code here, apparently markdown doesn't support this.
The code I am trying to run is:

```py
#%% #for jupyter notebook 

import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


LNA_w2Path_PAC_AND_PSP = pd.read_csv('../../Results/CSV/LNA_w2Path_PAC_AND_PSP.csv')
LNA_w2Path_PAC_AND_PSP.columns = LNA_w2Path_PAC_AND_PSP.columns.str.strip().str.lower().str.replace(' ', '_').str.replace('(', '').str.replace(')', '').str.replace('/', '').str.replace('=','_').str.replace(';','')
plt.figure()
plt.plot(LNA_w2Path_PAC_AND_PSP.net18net049_h_0__pac_db20vv_harmonic_0_x/1E9, LNA_w2Path_PAC_AND_PSP.net18net049_h_0__pac_db20vv_harmonic_0_y, linewidth=2.0)
plt.ylabel("$\mathrm{Harmonic \ response \ (dB)}$")
plt.xlabel("$\mathrm{Frequency \ (GHz)}$")
plt.title("Harmonic response of LNA+2-Path Filter")
plt.grid(True, which="both")
plt.show()
```

If I simply run a `python3 myfile.py` it works fine.

**EDIT**

My `.json` file looks like this:

```
{
    "git.autofetch": true,
    "python.pythonPath": "/home/theis/anaconda3",
    "window.zoomLevel": 2,
    "editor.find.addExtraSpaceOnTop": false,
    "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
    "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
    "python.jediEnabled": false,
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Dracula Soft",
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": false,
    "python.linting.enabled": false,
    "languageTool.language": "en-US",
    "julia.enableTelemetry": true,
    "python.terminal.executeInFileDir": true
}
```

**EDIT2**:

So I added `"cwd": "${fileDirname}"` to my `launch.json` and tried to run this code in both debugger and using the jupyter notebook extension:

```py
#%%

import os
print("Hello World!")
print(os.getcwd())
```

The debugger returns:

```sh
Hello World!
/home/theis/code/N_path_intership/PlottingCode/python
```

and the jupyter notebook extension returns:

```sh
Hello World!
/home/theis/code/N_path_intership/PlottingCode
```

Comment: Probably that the current working directory of your debugger is different from the one of your default running terminal

Comment: How I could set so both are the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the debug menu, click on the little setting icon to open `launch.json`. Your file should look like that:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
    {
            "name": "Python: Current File (Integrated Terminal)",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
    }, 

    //... other settings, but I modified the "Current File" setting above ...
}
```

You can add a `cwd` key (which means current working directory) and set it to what you want:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
    {
            "name": "Python: Current File (Integrated Terminal)",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}/<WhateverYouWant>"
    }, 

    //... other settings, but I modified the "Current File" setting above ...
}
```

It should solve your problem with the right path.

Comment: Should I truly add something after the fileDirname i.e: `"${fileDirname}/myfolder"` because as far I understood the fileDirname already does the job of getting the path by itself. I have added `"cwd": "${fileDirname}"` without any success.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this answer  can help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49275867/9628974

It's about changing the VSCode settings to execute python in the file's firectory.

Comment: This was set already (I have added the .json file in the EDIT)