# Running .py and files from directory in vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Disclaimer; if you are not an angry coder skip directly to the question. - I assume someone will point out that a similar question has been asked and answered, and you are probably right. But the question was not answered in the similar post: Trouble opening files in python with VS Code

My question:
Just installed vscode and ran into a problem with the path. When I run some simple python code to open and read data I receive an error that the file is not found.

Now I don't know vscode but the way I started the program is simply by launching from Anaconda. navigated to the folder containing the .py and data.acc files from inside vscode file explore.
i ran the .py with code runner and receive the error, I also ran it with "run in terminal" and error.

However, if I drag and drop the same folder onto vscode and start a new instance of vscode I don't have this problem.
If run it directly from the terminal, navigating to the folder containing the files = no problem.

I assume this has something to do with workspaces?
The problem is not in the python code, if this is not a typical problem it must be some a path or a configuration problem. Is there a VScode expert here on stack?

```py
filename = "data.acc"
file = open(filename, "r")
for line in file:
   print(line)
```

output

```py
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data.acc'
```

#### vscode has settings has apprently changed a bit lately, several setting are now point and click. Changing cdw in code runner and vscode solved the problem.. the question was answered in: Trouble opening files in python with VS Code but the setting has changed.

- Thanks for the help

Comment: Are you python script and file you're trying to open in the same directory?

Comment: @OlvinRoght yes its in the same folder

Comment: Launch this code `print(os.getcwd())` and check the output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trouble opening files in python with VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49143852/trouble-opening-files-in-python-with-vs-code)

Comment: Try to use absolute path to your file, or explicitly use relative path from the path of your script. Looks like the cwd of your python interpreter isn't the one your python script is in.

Comment: And there is one answer with +4 in the thread pointed by @OlvinRoght. Looks like a solution...

Comment: @OlvinRoght -