# I am trying to open a file in VS Code (python) with the input command. It works in IDLE but in VS not all the lines in the text file are read

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am trying to open and read a text file in VS Code (I installed the Python IntelliSense (Pylance) extension) using the input command. I can run the program with the Python IDLE, but in VS Studio Code, not all the lines of my text file are read. Does someone know why? Thank you for your help

```
fname = input("Enter a file name: ") 
fh = open(fname, "r") 
dh = fh.read() 
lx = dh.upper() 
ly = lx.rstrip() 
print(ly) 
fh.close()
```

I set this to True "python.terminal.executeInFileDir": true

Answer (score 0):

It may be something to do with the path that VS Code is using compared to the path that the Python IDLE is using. Have a look at the comments to the question in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49143852/trouble-opening-files-in-python-with-vs-code) Stack Overflow page. You can try inserting the absolute path to the file instead of *fname* to confirm that this is true.